# Export reg value to csv

Tags: windows, powershell, regedit

i have 1 question:

i need verify 3 reg key on 20 pc and export result on csv file.

I used this string

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path hklm:"\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\" -Name "keyname" | Export-csv -path "csvpath"
```

and recive the all value for thi key but i don't need see the "PSPath, PSParentPath, PSChildName, PSDrive, PSProvider.

now i was thinking of making a script with variables to simplify it, but at this point i would like it to tell me even if the key was not found and the basic thing i can run it from the DC to all machines (about 20).

this could be a starting point

```
$key1 = name key 1

$key2 = name key 2

$key3 = name key 3

$hostname= hostname

$regkey= get-itemprperty -path ecc....
```

and now i'm seeing how you implement the verification loop and export everything to csv

thx

Comment: You can use `Select-Object` with `-ExcludeProperty` switch -> `Get-ItemProperty -Path hklm:"\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\" -Name "keyname" | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty PSPath,PSParentPath,PSChildName,PSDrive,PSProvider`

Comment: its good idea. now what is the fastest way to get this info on remote pc that are in domain?

Comment: Not quite sure what you try to verify. The `-Name` parameter for `Get-ItemProperty` specifies the name of the **property or properties to retrieve**. (wildcard characters are permitted), but you speak of retrieving the registry **Key**. If you need to verify if a **key** with that name exists, use `Test-Path -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\$key1"`. To scan multiple computers, use [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)

Answer (score 0):

To verify the key existence, use `Test-Path`.

Computer names and Key names as arrays of strings.

No experience with remoting, I think you'll be using `Invoke-Command`, but this should give you an idea of looping and getting all non-PS properties:

```
Computer1
Computer2
Computer3
'@ -split '\n'

$keyNames = @'
KeyName1
KeyName2
KeyName3
`@ -split '\n'

ForEach ( $Comoputer in $Computers) {
    ForEach ( $KeyName in $KeyNames ) {
        If ( Test-Path $KeyName )
        {
            $AllProps = ($key = Get-Item $KeyName).Property
            (Get-ItemProperty $key).PSobject.Properties | where name -in $AllProps | select Name , Value
            <<  Create output   >>
        }
        Else
        {
            "$ComputerName: $KeyName not found."
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv "\\Path\to\CsvFile"
```

Answer (score 0):

To probe multiple computers for 3 registry properties and output the result in a CSV file, you can use `Invoke-Command` like below:

```
$computers     = 'pc01','pc02','pc03'  # etc. the 20 computers you want to probe
$propertynames = 'property1','property2','property3'  # you may use wildcards here

# loop over the computers
$result = foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    if (!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
        Write-Warning "Computer '$computer' is not responding"
        continue   # skip this computer and proceed with the next
    }
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
        $regPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
        # create a temporary Hashtable to store the items
        $hash = [ordered]@{}
        # loop over the properties
        foreach ($prop in $using:propertynames) {
            $entry = Get-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name $prop -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            if ($entry) {
                $hash['ComputerName'] = $using:computer
                $entry = $entry | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty PS*
                # use a loop in case you have used wildards for the property names 
                foreach ($item in $entry.PsObject.Properties) {
                    $hash[$item.Name] = $item.Value
                }
            }
            else {
                Write-Warning "Could not find property '$prop'"
            }
        }
        if ($hash.Count) {
            # output the hash converted to PSObject
            [PsCustomObject]$hash
        }
    }
}

# remove the properties added by Invoke-Command
$result = $result | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty PS*,RunspaceId

# output to gridview
$result | Out-GridView

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Path\To\TheResults.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```